# Removing items from an object where linked model has 0 items

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

How to I check if a nested model object, has any items.

Ie. if I have an object/viewmodel:

```
    public class CarViewModel
    {
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public virtual IQueryable<Feature> Features { get; set; }
    }

    public class Feature
    {
    public string Offer { get; set; }
    public decimal Rate { get; set; }
    public virtual CarViewModel CarViewModel { get; set; }
    }
```

...and it is populated as follows - so that 1 car object has 2 additional features, and the other car object, has no additional features:

```
[
{"Type":"SoftTop","ID":1,
"Features":
    [{"Offer":"Alloys","Rate":"500"},{"Offer":"Standard","Rate":"100"}]},
{"Type":"Estate","ID":2,
"Features":[]}
]
```

So in my code, I had "Cars" populated with the data above:

```
foreach (var car in Cars)
{
    if (!car.Features.Any())
    {
        car.Type = "Remove";
    }
 }
```

However, I get the message: `This method is not supported against a materialized query result.` at the if (!car.Features.Any()) line.

I got the same error when trying `if (car.Features.Count()==0)`

Is there a way of checking if the number of Features is 0?

Or is there a linq way of removing any items from the object, where the number of features is 0?

Thank you,

Mark

**UPDATE**

I changed the viewModel to use IEnumerable and then the following:

```
cars=cars.Where(x => x.Feature.Count()>0).ToList();
```

That seems to work - although I'm not 100% sure.  If anyone can say whether this is a "bad" fix or not, I'd appreciate it.

Thanks, Mark

Comment: It might depend on how the features class is initialised. It might be tht you need to check car.Features == null. Try checking the value in the debugger.

Comment: Hi - thanks for the suggestion.  I changed to (car.Features==null) - but even for the one where there are no features, it shows as False.

Comment: Have you tried `Features.Count() == 0`?

Comment: Hi @Brett - yes, I tried: if (car.Features.Count()==0) - and got the "...materialized query result" error.

Comment: Try `car.Features.ToList().Count`

Comment: Hi @James - yes that worked thank you.  I don't know if your solution, or my update in my answer is best - but you answered my question - so if you add an answer, I'll mark it as such.  Cheers, Mark

Comment: @MarkTait your update seems to refer to different code than what you have specified in your example. Is `x.Occs.Count() > 0` effectively `car.Features.Count() > 0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try fetching the results first then checking the count

```
car.Features.ToList().Count
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there any anything wrong with the fix - when you're using `IQueryable<T>` that came from a Linq to DB (L2S, Entity Framework, etc) you pretty much have to materialise it before you can use things like `Any()` or `Count()` when you ask for these things inside `foreach`.

As to why this is - I actually am not 100% certain and I believe that the error is a bit misleading in this respect, but I *think* that what it's complaining about is that neither `Cars` not `car.Features()` has actually been fully evaluated and run yet (i.e you are only starting to hit the database at the point when you go `foreach ...` in your code because it's `IQueryable<T>`).

However on a broader note I'd recommend you not use `IQueryable<T>` in your Viewmodels, much safer to use `IEnumerable<T>` - no chance of accidentally setting off a database access when rendering your view, for example.

And also when you are returning data from your DataLayer or wherever, a good rule of thumb is to materialise it *as quickly as possible* so as to be able to move on with an actual list of actual things as opposed to a *"promise to go and look*" for certain things in the database at some unspecificed point in the future :)  So your DataLayers should only ever return `IEnumerable<T>'s`

You can always cast an IEnumerable to IQueryable if for some reason you need to...